# In Nothing - June 12th 1799 Letter by John Marshall

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He was in our late army a lieut. Colo. & he performd the duties of that office with reputation. It is probable that he may feel wounded at being offerd the same grade under others whom he then commanded & who are perhaps **in nothing** his superiors. It is presumd that officers in the actual army will command those of the same grade in the eventual army. If we are correct in this then Colonels Bentley & Parker who were both subalterns when Colo. Cropper was a field officer, & who are not supposd to have manifested any superiority over him, will now take rank of him. ([Source](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%20Author%3A%22Marshall%2C%20John%22&s=1111311121&sa=&r=20&sr=))

Could someone please explicate and demystify **in nothing**? My guess would be that Colonel Cropper's superiors admittedly possesses nothing that would make them veritably superior?

Comment: I would agree with you. This is clarified in the subsequent sentences.

Comment: Possibly an erroneous transcription from OCR.

Comment: It just means they are not better than him at anything.

Comment: Probably not an erroneous OCR to judge from http://books.google.ie/books?id=EpuW5UohJIsC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22who+are+perhaps+in+nothing+his+superiors%22&source=bl&ots=OsMAuVuNBn&sig=ce2fiOw5WYCMUpSUl2kqBXCL7z0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mNiTUtDkFof07Aa084HAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22who%20are%20perhaps%20in%20nothing%20his%20superiors%22&f=false which is clearly a different transcription (it updates the abbreviations of rank to the modern forms) but matches the wording of this phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun senses of *superior*, most often refer to rank or status, but can also refer to quality, such as [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/superior#entryPageContent).

I might say that my partner (for example) is my superior in cooking and music (for example), which I could also phrase as:

> My partner is in cooking and music my superior.

In saying that, I don't allow that she is better than me in all ways, in coding, for example, I'm her superior.

In saying "... [they] are in nothing his superiors", a claim is made that there is no quality (or at least, none by which one would judge an officer and a gentleman) in which the other colonels are better than the colonel being discussed. In saying "... [they] are perhaps in nothing his superiors", the claim is weakened by the "perhaps", but the gist is the same.